# How to create multiple tabs without xml in android

Tags: android, tabwidget

I found a lot of examples to create tabs using an xml file in android, but I need to create multiple tabs programmatically. Please guide me.

```
<TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:tag="tab0"
            android:text="Tab 1"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:tag="tab1"
            android:text="Tab 2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:tag="tab2"
            android:text="Tab 3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />

    </TabWidget>
```

How can I write this programmatically instead of the above xml code.

Comment: Use ActionBar tabs! See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Comment: http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-tabwidget-example.html

Comment: if i use import android.app.ActionBar it shows error "Cannot be resolved"

Comment: i use android version 2.3.3. ActionBAr is not workingin it

Comment: @Chintan: pls update some example code,, my web filter blocked used blogspot url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check **[Tab With Swipe](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/)** example. It has implementation of tabs without xml files.

But there is XML layout for each fragment. You can drop it as per your requirement.

Comment: i need to create without the layout xml file. i need to write programmatically without any xml files

Comment: @sivanesan1, glad to help.. up-vote will be great pleasure.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your TabActivity:

```
private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c)
{
  Intent intent=new Intent(this, c);
  TabHost.TabSpec spec=Your_TabHost.newTabSpec("tab"+labelId);

  View tabIndicator=LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
  TextView title=(TextView)tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
  title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12);
  title.setText(labelId);
  ImageView icon=(ImageView)tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
  icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

  spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
  spec.setContent(intent);
  Your_TabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

Add tab(s) via this way(Still in TabActivity):

```
addTab("Your tab title", R.drawable.your_tab_icon, SomeActivity.class);
```

But I still strongly suggest you to use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) in android lower than 4.0, since Tab have been deprecated...